# How can you echo input to the bc command from bash?

Tags: macos, bash, bc

I am trying to create a bash alias or function which can pipe text to the stdin of the unix command bc.

I first attempted:

```
alias semitone="echo \"scale=10; e(l(2.))\" | bc"
```

Which bash parses ok, but it fails with a bc runtime error:

```
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=12): Function l not defined.
```

In tcsh:

```
alias semitone 'echo "scale=10; e(l(2.)/12.)" | bc'
```

works totally fine and gives correct output:

```
1.0594630943
```

I also attempted using a bash function:

```
semitone() { echo "scale=10; e(l(2.)/12.)" | bc ; }
```

which returns the same bc runtime error.  Not sure how the output is getting munged.  Any insight?

Comment: That code doesn't work outside a function or alias either. Try just running `echo "scale=10; e(l(2.)/12.)" | bc` at your prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For math functions to be defined in `bc`, you need to specify the `-l` option. Otherwise, `bc` will tell you that functions like `l` are not defined.

So it has nothing to do with the alias. I have no idea how it works with `tcsh` -- it doesn't on my (ubuntu) system. Although including the `-l`, even through the alias -- as in `semitone -l` -- works fine both with `bash` and `tcsh`

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  I had bc aliased as bc -l under both tcsh and bash under linux.  Been too long for me to remember the function of -l